# MySQL, how to display descending age of children and children of the same age listed alphabetically?

Tags: mysql

I am having difficulties  in the order by result. It gives me all the info I need but the children with the same age don't show ordered by surname alphabetically.

I need a list showing the name and age (in years) of each child on the day that the query is
run.
The list should be sorted in descending order of age (i.e. oldest children first) with
children of the same age listed alphabetically by surname, first name.

Here is my syntax

```
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, child_dob, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS age 
FROM Children 
ORDER BY child_dob, child_sname, child_fname;
```

I'm really stuck, hope someone can shed a light please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You forgot two things:

1. You need to order by age, not by date of birth--unless you really only want to order by last name for children born on the exact same day.
2. To show oldest children first, you need to order by age with the `DESC` keyword.

Here's the proper query:

```
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, child_dob, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS age 
FROM Children 
ORDER BY age DESC, child_sname, child_fname;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are ordering by `child_dob`, which is presumably a date field, instead of by `age` (which is the child's age in years).

```
ORDER BY age DESC, child_sname, child_fname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, child_dob, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS age 
FROM Children 
ORDER BY age, child_sname, child_fname;
```